# Does Python have exclusive and logical operator?

Tags: python, logical-operators

Does Python have **exclusive AND** operator (such as && in C#)?

I have not managed to find it in Python docs (nor explanation why it is not supported).

Thanks!

Comment: What is "exclusive AND"? Do you mean "exclusive NOR", ie "(A and B) OR not (A and B)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python equivalent of C#'s `&&` operator is spelled `and`.

See the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: You mean, if I evaluate expression: False and True, result will be False without evaluating the right side of expression?

Comment: @IvanJovovic That's called short-circuiting, and is nothing to do with exclusivity.

Comment: @Duncan: Thanks, documentation link explains it all.